# Understanding the Relationship between the Normal Vectors and Planes

Tags: calculus

I'm studying for a Calc III midterm and I am running into a bit of a conceptual issue that I know can't be true. Can anyone tell me where the logic falls through?

Suppose I have an arbitrary line contained in a plane and a normal vector to said plane. I know that planes can be defined by the components of their normal vectors so let the normal vector be $\vec{n}=\langle a,b,c\rangle$ and the equation of the plane be $ax+by+cz=0$. Let the arbitrary line be defined with $\vec{r}(t)=t\langle a,b,c\rangle$ with $\vec{r}(0)=0$. Now parameterized the normal vector as $\vec{n}(t)=t\langle a,b,c\rangle$. If I wrote $\vec{r}(t)$ as a set of symmetric equations I would get: $$\frac{x}{a}=\frac{y}{b}=\frac{z}{c}$$ and if I wrote $\vec{n}(t)$ as symmetric equations I would get:$$\frac{x}{a}=\frac{y}{b}=\frac{z}{c}$$I know that two lines are parallel if the have the same direction components so I would think that $\vec{r}(t)$ is parallel to $\vec{n}(t)$ but that can't be true because the normal vector is perpendicular to every line in the plane. If I had to guess, I made a mistake in defining one of the two lines because they are identical so that would force them to be parallel. I guess my question really should be which line am I defining wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote that $\vec r(t)=t(a,b,c)$. But you also wrote that the line $\vec r$ is contained in the plane $ax+by+cz=0$. That's can't be, since the line $\vec r$ that you defined is actual *orthogonal* to the plane.

Comment: So if I am understanding, my mistake is coming from how to define a line that is contained in a plane. Could you explain how to do so?

Also, do you think I would find the mistake in my logic if I defined a line from a line and a point? I would get the normal vector with a usual cross-product and then test it with the line that I used to make the plane.

Comment: If you want to find a line passing through the origin and contained in the plane $ax+by+cz=0$, take any point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ from that plane distinct from the origin and consider the line $\vec r(t)=t(x_0,y_0,z_0)$.

Comment: That fixed everything. I know this isn't the place for it, but thank you. I'm new to posting here, should I delete my post now that I realized my mistake?

Comment: I don't think so. Others may have the same doubt.